# Since migration to Kotlin, Maven builds fail because test resources are not added to classpath

Tags: maven, kotlin

I have a Java project migrated to Kotlin, with Maven modules.

If I try to build one of the modules with IntelliJ, the test resources files will be present in the classpath (`/target/test-classes/`), causing a test to succeed.

On the other hand, when I build the module with Maven, the resource will not be added to the classpath (`/target/test-classes/`), causing a test to fail.

My Kotlin Maven configuration is pretty much [pulled from Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#compiling-kotlin-and-java-sources).

How can I properly add the resources to the test classpath?

Answer (score 0):

In the Maven properties, disable incremental compilation. I don't why this is happening.

```
<properties>
    <kotlin.version>1.2.21</kotlin.version>
    <!--<kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>-->
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    <junit.platform.version>1.0.0</junit.platform.version>
</properties>
```